# iPhone : How to save a view as image ??? (ex.save what you draw )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimage

I found some sample is teach you how to draw on iphone

but it does not say how to save a view as image ?

Does anyone got idea ???

Or any sample will be helpful : )

actually,I'm trying to save user's signature as a image and upload it to server.

Thanks

Webber

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
UIView *view = // your view    
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This gives the image which you can store using –

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

where path is location you want to save to.

Comment: sorry , can you tell more detail about this code ... I have no idea to use it ...

Comment: The idea is to generate a `UIImage` object for the view so that we can save it as an image. For that we use a bit of `Core Graphics`. We take the view's layer (each view has a layer which represents the visual aspect of the view) and draw it into an image context (Imagine context as a drawing board). Once the drawing is finished, we generate the `UIImage` object of the context. This we convert to data in jpeg representation using a framework function `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0)`. Note the `1.0` is the quality of the image you desire with `1.0` being the best

Comment: Once we have an `NSData` object we use its method `writeToFile:atomically` to save the image at the desired file `path`. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Two notes: **1.** You should check for zero bounds size. **2.** In general it is better to store drawed images in PNG using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick method to render any UIView as image. It takes into account the iOS version the device is running on and makes use of the relevant method for acquiring an image representation of a UIView.

More specifically, now there is better method (i.e., drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) for taking screenshot of a UIView on devices running on iOS 7 or later versions, which is, from what i've read, considered to be a more performant way as compared to "renderInContext" method.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW217

**USAGE EXAMPLE:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> // don't forget to import this framework in file header.

UIImage* screenshotImage = [self imageFromView:self.view]; //or any view that you want to render as an image.
```

**CODE:**

```
#define IS_OS_7_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)

- (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view {

    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    UIImage *image;

    if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
        //Optimized/fast method for rendering a UIView as image on iOS 7 and later versions.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, scale);
        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    } else {
        //For devices running on earlier iOS versions.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size,YES, scale);
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In MonoTouch/C# as an extension method:

```
public static UIImage ToImage(this UIView view) {
    try {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.ViewForBaselineLayout.Bounds.Size);
        view.Layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
        return UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    } finally {
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    }
}
```