# How to Scale uiview and everything inside it (other custom drawn uiviews) with animation?

Tags: uiview, xcode4.2, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a uiview that contains other custom drawn uiview inside it. Now I want that, when a user clicks this parent view it would expand to a new defined frame with animation.
I had some success using the animation block. The problem is that the expanded view is just the scaled version of the unexpanded uiview and hence it is a little pixelated. By calling the child views `setneedsdisplay()` after the animation block now the end result of expanding the view is sharp( i.e. not pixelated). But in transitions it still pixelated.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but I'll give it a shot anyway...

> By calling the child views setneedsdisplay() after the animation block
>   now the end result of expanding the view is sharp( i.e. not
>   pixelated)...Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

One way that you could have done this in Xcode 4.2 is to insert an image view containing a picture of the larger version of the view. You could create that picture by [rendering the view in an image context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6079273/643383). This approach will work best, of course, if the animation expands the view by simply scaling it; if you're moving subviews around during the animation, a static image obviously won't be helpful.

Now that Xcode 4.2 is largely a distant memory and devices have a lot more horsepower, using autolayout constraints to manage the sizes and positions of subviews during the expansion should yield pretty good results.