# How to save a view as an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion. In this app I let the user "sign" their name by drawing on a view. I want to save this "signature" to a real image so that I can upload it to the server.

I think I have found an Objective-C solution here: [iPhone : How to save a view as image ??? (ex.save what you draw )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079273/iphone-how-to-save-a-view-as-image-ex-save-what-you-draw)

The code for that looks like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I have tried to "translate" this code into Ruby like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signature.bounds.size)
signature.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext)
image = UIImage.UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

But I get this error when running it:

```
uninitialized constant SignatureController::UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext (NameError)
2013-01-27 14:20:29.943 buy_app[18384:13d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NameError', reason: 'signature_controller.rb:88:in `save': uninitialized constant SignatureController::UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way of saving a normal view into an image?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I solved it like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signature.bounds.size)
signature.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
image = UIImage.UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signature.bounds.size)
signature.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
image = UIImage.UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Comment: For a retina display you would want to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)` Otherwise it's going to downscale the image to 1/4 resolution.